# String Character Comparison

Tags: vb.net, string, character

I need to compare the characters in two strings in VB and get  a numerical value for the amount of different characters. I am using this in order to see if the two words are spelt the same by checking the amount of differences, though I have to give credit if they are similar - hence the numerical value needed. Thanks very much!

Some Pseudo code that might make things more clear:

```
    Dim string1, string2 As String
    Dim change As Integer


    [On button press]


    string1 = TextBox1.Text
    string2 = TextBox2.Text

    CompareCharacters(string1, string2)

    FormatNumber of differences between strings  = change


    MsgBox(change)
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: What if the strings don't have the same length ?

Comment: What do you mean by "amount of different characters"?  Consider "abc" and "axbc".  Is that 1, 2, or 3 differences?

Comment: That would be one difference, I'm using it to determine if the words are spelled the same (in hindsight I realise some more context would have been helpful)

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
Friend Function AmountOfDifferentCharacters(ByVal String1 As String, 
                                            ByVal String2 As String) As Integer

    Return (From c As Char In String2 Where Not String1.Contains(c)).Count

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this looks right but how would I implement this?

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the strings and compare each character:

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 0
For index = 0 to Math.Min(string1.Length, string2.Length) - 1
  If string1.Substring(index, 1) <> string2.Substring(index, 1) Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
  End If
Next
Dim change As String = cnt.ToString()
```

Comment: You might want to add the remaining chars to the `cnt` variable on deceleration. `Dim cnt As Integer = Math.Abs(string1.Length - string2.Length)`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Yes, you might. That depends on whether you want them included in the difference count or not. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Trust me, this was NOT me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried using this though all values seemed to equal 0 no matter what was entered. Thanks again!